# Firefox website content going beyond margin

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have designed a website to be dynamic so that the width of the browser allows for the content to adjust. However on this specific page, the size of the browser in firefox ONLY is giving me problems:

The text goes beyond it's margins and clashes into the image on firefox when adjusting the screen size. Try it out and let me know. The css is very simple as well.

```css
.nav-phone>a:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #fbc076;
}

.nav>a:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #fbc076;
}

.newbox {
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

.readiblecolumns {
    background-color: white;
}

.readiblecolumns>p {
    line-height: 1;
}

/* Desktop */
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {

    .newbox {
        height: auto;
        width: 80vw;
    }

    /* Reads Like Newspaper */
    .readiblecolumns {
        width: 80vw;
        padding: 20px;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }

    .readiblecolumns>p {
        font-size: 100%;
    }

    .profile {
        height: 480px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .profile img {
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

}

/* Tablet */
@media screen and (min-width: 520px) and (max-width: 959px) {

    .newbox {
        height: auto;
        width: 80vw;
    }

    .readiblecolumns {
        width: 80vw;
        padding: 20px;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }

    .readiblecolumns>p {
        font-size: 100%;
    }

    .profile {
        height: 320px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .profile img {
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

}

/* Phone */
@media screen and (max-width: 519px) {

    .newbox {
        height: auto;
        width: 90vw;
    }

    .readiblecolumns {
        width: 90vw;
        padding: 15px;
    }
}
```

The html is as follows:

```
<div class="newbox">
    <div class="readiblecolumns">
        <div class="profile">
            <img src="Pictures/MyLife/mypicture.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <p>Miusov, as a man man of breeding and deilcacy, could not but feel some inwrd qualms, when he reached the Father Superior's with Ivan: he felt ashamed of havin lost his temper. He felt that he ought to have disdaimed that despicable wretch, Fyodor Pavlovitch, too much to have been upset by him in Father Zossima's cell, and so to have forgotten himself. "Teh monks were not to blame, in any case," he reflceted, on the steps. "And if they're decent people here (and the Father Superior, I understand, is a nobleman) why not be friendly and courteous withthem? I won't argue, I'll fall in with everything, I'll win them by politness, and show them that I've nothing to do with that Aesop, thta buffoon, that Pierrot, and have merely been takken in over this affair, just as they have."</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, when I resize the page from the max window size to the smallest, I just see the text wrap around the img, than move below the img.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have noticed that `img` inside multi-column is handled differently in Firefox. The overflowed portion of image is visible instead of being hidden

To fix this, add the following code:

```
.profile {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```